# Blender console render: Finished

Tags: rendering, command-line, error

I used blender console render for batch files.
Sometimes files or frames doesn't produce any result. I got only "Finished" console string.

After that render is stopped and no files was saved. I use the same settings for number of files, and sometimes the same frame "Finished", but sometimes renders successfully.

I expected a beauty render and a Z pass from compositor.

If I render "Finished" file or frame through Blender UI, I get the result in compositor preview and saved files from compositor output, but no output files from general render output tab. Blender console (in Blender UI) doesn't show any exceptions or errors.

**What the reason of unsuccessful render and how to avoid it?**

Blender 2.78c

OS X

Command:

```
/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender -b "/Users/IlyaKanatov/Work/Graphic Treasury/2017-03-03 Confetti Kit/Sandbox/Background - Rect Wall - Paper.blend" -o "/Users/IlyaKanatov/Work/Graphic Treasury/2017-03-03 Confetti Kit/Final/Background - Rect Wall - Paper" -x 1 -f 1
```

Download blend file (console log included to the blend file): http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46164

Console log - Part 1: http://pasteall.org/336104/text

Console log - Part 2: http://pasteall.org/336105/text

Thanks!

[image: Blender Console Render: Finished]
[image: Render settings]

Comment: @cegaton f 1 is what I need, and I got Z pass successfully with this settings. But sometimes some command-line batch renders ends with the "Finished" echo and NO files was saved. Not the beauty pass, not the Z pass.

Comment: not sure what's up with this one, I just tried the file you provided (on a Windows machine though) using this command `blender.exe -b "Background - Rect Wall - Paper.blend" -o "D:\Background - Rect Wall - Paper" -x 1 -f 1` and it worked fine. I get a beauty pass, but of course not the z-pass you define in the file output node, because the given location does not exist on my system. But the rendering finishes just fine. One thing I notice is that the memory consumption in your logs is five times higher than for me. Have you provided everything?

Comment: just tested with a different output path for the z-pass, and this renders fine too. Do you really need `progressive refine` turned on? It slows down rendering this scene a lot actually.

Comment: @aliasguru thanks so much for your time! Unfortunately I'm trying to get any result from this file right now, and without luck. I'll try it on my virtual Windows machine. I like the "Progressive Refine" because it useful - you can see all scene from first passes, I didn't know it slows render, thanks! I'll try to turn it off.

Comment: I have a number of similar files, but exactly this broken. And I dunno why. (

Comment: Does it work for you if you render from the UI? In other words, is this a problem which you only have on the command line, or does it also happen within Blender UI?